# Virtual NIC: "SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address" but gets created

Tags: networking, network-interface, ifconfig

I am having some trouble with the apparently easy task of creating a virtual network adapter on a physical network card in my Linux system (custom distribution, Debian-based).

If I run

```
ifconfig eth0:1 10.50.55.130 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

everything goes just fine: the virtual NIC is silently added and correctly shown by `ifconfig`.

I want the definition for this virtual NIC to appear in `/etc/network/interfaces` though. I have added the following stanza.

```
# virtual NIC
# auto eth0:1
iface eth0:1 inet static
    address 10.50.55.130
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

First line commented out because as of now I am not interested in having the system bring the network interface up automatically.

Everything seems fine.

If I run `ifup eth0:1`, though, I get `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Cannot assign requested address`.

What I really can't wrap my head around is that the virtual NIC is actually created. Here's the output from `ifconfig`.

```
can0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-                        00-00-00  
      UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
      RX packets:1206446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:193280 errors:0 dropped:12 overruns:0 carrier:12
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:10 
      RX bytes:7645126 (7.2 MiB)  TX bytes:1393003 (1.3 MiB)
      Interrupt:68 

can1      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
      UP RUNNING NOARP  MTU:16  Metric:1
      RX packets:299171 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:10 
      RX bytes:2393368 (2.2 MiB)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
      Interrupt:71 

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:5d:ad:c2:30:30  
      inet addr:10.90.100.43  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.248.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1560275 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:790 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:96964255 (92.4 MiB)  TX bytes:176882 (172.7 KiB)
      Interrupt:56 

eth0:1    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:5d:ad:c2:30:30 
      inet addr:10.50.55.130  Bcast:10.50.55.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      Interrupt:56 

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 98:5d:ad:c2:30:32  
      inet addr:169.254.8.141  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:140932 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:140932 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:8522761 (8.1 MiB)  TX bytes:8522761 (8.1 MiB)
```

Why am I getting this error? Or... Why does the NIC get created?

I'll add that if I invoke `ifup -f eth0:1` (with the force option) no error messages are shown AND the virtual network adapter is brought up just fine.

Comment: Interface names like `eth0:1` do not denote separate interfaces, not even virtual ones. They are just aliases, i.e. different names for the real interface. Because they are just aliases, they don't have separate state – for example, `eth0:1` can't be down if `eth0`is up. This alias mechanism is only needed because the old `ifconfig` tool can only handle one address per device name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ifconfig` is considered obsolete these days. Try to use `ip` tool instead. All recent distributions should support it, it's part of `iproute` tool set.

If you just want additional IP address on the interface, use following command:

```
ip addr add 10.50.55.130/24 dev eth0
```

And I agree with Johan Myréen's comment bellow your question.

Comment: More interestingly yet, in certain situations `ifconfig` does not show alias create with `ip`. +1 for the `ip` recommendation.

Comment: @RuiFRibero Try adding `label eth0:1` to the `ip address add ...` line.

Answer (score 1):

apart from command line method, the preferred method for Debian based system is to use networking configuration files.

The alias method prefers to use such order: `eth0, eth:0:0, eth0:1,` ...

So first alias to system would be eth0:0 and to achieve this persistent across system reboots, create a file `/etc/network/interfaces.d/eth0` with such content:

```
auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth0:0 inet static
      address 10.50.55.130/24
```

Or you can edit directly the file `/etc/network/interfaces` but this is not recommended as it can be overwritten automatically.

The key is to use format of address with slash subnet, and not to use `netmask` keyword anymore: `address 10.50.55.130/24`

And of course do

`service networking restart`

to test the configuration.
Check afterwards with command:

`service networking status`

and

`ip address`

Please note, that like mentioned in comments, the actual name of the interface can be any, thus make sure to check interface names with `ip addr` command and use that name and amend `:0` and so on to that, like *enp3s0f0:0* and *enp3s0f0:1* and so on.

Comment: I made almost the same thing for several IPs, except that in order to restart successfully networking.service, I had to replace the legacy eth0 by my new interface name enp3s0f0, even if eth0 was the one in interfaces ... `auto enp3s0f0:1 iface enp3s0f0:1 inet static address aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/30